# FB.login() fails with "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame" on Android Chrome but not desktop Chrome

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, cross-domain, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a Facebook JS SDK login flow here: https://web.triller.co/#/user/login

When the user taps the Facebook button, the following function is executed:

```
loginFacebook()
{
    const fbPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        FB.login(resp => {
            if (resp.authResponse)
            {
                resolve(resp.authResponse.accessToken);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log(resp);
                reject(new Error('Facebook login canceled or failed.'));
            }
        });
    });

    return fbPromise
        .then(accessToken => api.postJson('user/login_facebook', { accessToken }))
        .then(this._handleLogin.bind(this));
}
```

Basically, it calls `FB.login()`, and expects to receive a valid `resp.authResponse`. Unfortunately, it doesn't, even after successfully authenticating on the Facebook popup/tab. Instead, we receive `{ authResponse: undefined, status: undefined }` and the following error from the browser:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with URL
>   'https://m.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?foo=bar'
>   from frame with URL 'https://web.triller.co/#/user/login?_k=cmzdb6'.
>   The frame attempting navigation is neither same-origin with the
>   target, nor is it the target's parent or opener.

The error occurs immediately after authenticating within the Facebook popup/tab, *and it only occurs on Android Chrome*. Desktop Chrome (on a Mac) does not show the same error. Safari on iOS does not show the error, either.

Any thoughts on what's going on? Why the difference between Android Chrome and desktop Chrome? Could it have something to do with the hash in the URL?

Comment: are you opening a new window for auth?

Comment: @SagarV `FB.login()` opens a new window. I'm not doing anything other than calling `FB.login()` and waiting for the callback.

Answer (score 1):

In desktop this issue can be caused by XFINITY Constant Guard Protection Suite Chrome extension. Disble it and problem will be solved.

In Android, try removing XFINITY or similar security extensions or applications (Norton security antivirus).

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008qKnIAI

Answer (score 1):

I think it fails because of the m.facebook.com/... based on this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules (see the case for http://en.example.com/dir/other.html and why it fails). Although it shouldn't based on what I've done with the fb api this is weird, try making a cors request instead as a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20254.

When the `window.open` is called without proper arguments, it will not be opened as expected.

It can be overcome by either updating the browser (for client, check the browser version and if old one, force them to update it).

Otherwise (not applicable for you since you can't change the FB function), pass the correct arguments to `window.open`

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly I only seem to get this when I am using the mobile device simulator in Chrome.

Looking at the source code for the [Facebook SDK](https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js) there is the following line:

```
 url: i.resolve(a.display == "touch" ? "m" : "www") + "/" + d.url,
```

Now `"m"` then becomes `"m.facebook.com"` whereas `"www"` becomes `"www.facebook.com"`. So it's using a different URL based on whether or not it's touch.

Now they're the same domain anyway, and the connect API is loaded from `facebook.net` (not `.com`) so it's not as simple as just being a different domain. However I suspect the issue could be related to this.

In either case when not in mobile device testing mode I don't get the error.